# Glut Project won't run .exe file on devc++

Tags: c++

First of all, sorry for my bad english. This is my first question on stackoverflow. I recently started studying about computer graphics and i want to try a DDA algorithm code from this website https://myprogworld.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/dda-line-algorithm-using-opengl/

I expecting that the result of code is like this, like the picture in the website:
[expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skuvd.png)

but when i run the code myself on devc++, it only open this: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBlvg.png), and the .exe file is not opening.

Anyone know the solution? Sorry if my language is really confusing. Thanks for anyone answering.

The code:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
float x1, x2, y1, y2;

void display(void)
{
    float dy, dx, step, x, y, k, Xin, Yin;
    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;

    if (abs(dx) > abs(dy))
    {
        step = abs(dx);
    }
    else
        step = abs(dy);

    Xin = dx / step;
    Yin = dy / step;

    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();

    for (k = 1; k <= step; k++)
    {
        x = x + Xin;
        y = y + Yin;

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        glEnd();
    }

    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-100, 100, -100, 100);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Enter the value of x1 : ");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("Enter the value of y1 : ");
    scanf("%f", &y1);
    printf("Enter the value of x2 : ");
    scanf("%f", &x2);
    printf("Enter the value of y2 : ");
    scanf("%f", &y2);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("DDA Line Algo");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiling this with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` brings up a few problems. First, you are applying `int abs(int)` to `float` values, which will cause the `float`s to be truncated; if you want the FP absolute values, use `double fabs(double)` instead, otherwise you would be wise to explicitly truncate the FP values using either `ceil()` or `floor()`, then casting to `int`.

Comment: On an aside, which version of Dev-C++ are you using? The IDE has passed through a few different hands, and the [current version](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/dev-cpp) is being maintained by Embarcadero Software (who also support the latest versions of the Borland software). If you are using the old Bloodshed Dev-C++, you may be using an outdated version of GCC.

Comment: Mind you, this is C code, not C++; while it isn't an issue in this case, compiling C as C++ could present problems.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).